# Webdriver logs for Firefox using RemoteWebDriver Object

Tags: java, selenium

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.setPreference("webdriver.log.file", "/tmp/firefox_browser.log");
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capability.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, firefoxProfile);
webdriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(node), capability)
```

firefox_browser.log is not created. This happens only when the driver object is created using RemoteWebDriver class, when driver object is created using FireFoxDriver then logs are created. Please help.